# WPF: Updating Polyline's Points property via binding causes lag

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, rendering, lag

I have a custom graph control that uses a `Polyline` object to render waveforms.

```
<Polyline Name="Line" Points="{Binding LinePoints}"
    Stroke="{Binding LineColor}"
    StrokeThickness="{Binding LineThickness}">
```

In my ViewModel, I will generate different sets of "LinePoints" every short while (50-200ms) via a `DispatcherTimer`. The binding works perfectly fine, I am getting animated waveform at the View, except that it is causing significant lag in the user interface. For example, when I right click on something else in the Window, the context menu would appear with very very laggy animation.

Of course, I could change the timer to tick every 500ms, and the lag would be significantly reduced. But, this would make my graph looks sloppy. Is there any methods I can do to shift some of these to another thread?

(Side note: The generation of `LinePoints` is not the main cause of the lag. Each generation is using about 1ms of execution time. This value is obtained from  `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`)

Comment: How do you know when you should update your Polyline control? What action within the app tells you to update it? Where I am going with it, I believe you are using wrong approach to solve your case.

Comment: The polyline is is simply simulating the waveform of a graph, and this waveform is expected to move and change very frequently.

Comment: You mentioned waveform, so it should update on sound parameters changing?

Comment: It simply updates when the waveform changes. The waveform can be from sound, or anything. But it is expected to change very frequently. At the moment, I am simulating it by having a function to generate thousands of `Point`s very 100ms.

Comment: Or rather, a generator function that is called every 100ms via a timer.

Answer (score 0):

So since the operation of calculating all the required points are heavy on UI you should use additional `Thread` to cover the calculation. `UI Thread` should only be responsible for representation, meaning it should only assign given value, not calculate it.

This is perfect use case for new `await async keywords` introduced in `4.5` framework version.

To achieve described behavior I would suggest using `Task class` as such:

```
private async void InvokeHandler()
{
   while(true)
   {
       // Passes variable to calculation method and waits for result without blocking.
       ViewModel.Points = await Task.Run(() => CalculatePoints(new object()));
       await Task.Delay(100);
   }
}
private Task<PointCollection> CalculatePoints(object requiredArguments)
{
    var points = new PointCollection();
    // Do calculations here with requiredArgument passed from a caller.
    return Task.FromResult(points);
}
```

**How does it work?** In `InvokeHandler` method you start up a `Task` which could essentially be another `Thread` (gathered from `ThreadPool` if current `Thread` does not have enough resourceses to run provided `Delegate`), which will not block your currently running `Thread` and after it finished executing it will return you a result (`PointCollection`).

Comment: Well, I can try this after I read a bit more on this topic. But this is probably not the main cause, because the calculation method only takes about 1ms per calculation. I would think that 1ms non-representation execution time within a 100ms render cycle should not cause lag.

Comment: @Jai If lag is purely caused by rendering of the actual Polyline. Then there is few options to actually reduce amount of points passed in at the time or improve hardware.